# Are there any career(s)/career fields that are advantageous for people with Asperger's in "theory"?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, psychology, aspergers

What is the psychology/cognitive validity of [this post reply for this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-Asperger-s-are-there-any-career-s-career-fields-that-are-advantageous-for-people-with-Aspergers-in-theory?ch=99&share=1052de25&srid=UYWXS)?

> "Most certainly, professions involving creating automation for processes that seem random. Hence, linguistics, computer science, mathematics, statistics, philosophy etc. All disciplines that have an inductive thought process. Therefore the careers which stem out of the aforementioned.
>
> More importantly, tasks should not be repetitive in nature, for example in web development, using the same frameworks to use the same type of websites. Rather, one should focus on the possibility of making a general framework which automates the tasks."

Comment: I was honestly going to ask this last week! The level and type of functioning would be significant in determining the best profession if it's even possible. Partifularly flexible work ours and forms of help may be necessary. Individuality would be significant